# OpenOSCAP scanner not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run OpenOSCAP on Ubuntu 16.04 and it is throwing the following error:

```
Title   The auditd service must be running in the Ubuntu operating system.
Rule    SV-95671r1_rule
Ident   CCI-000366
WARNING: Skipping rule that requires an unregistered check system or 
incorrect content reference to evaluate. Please consider providing a valid 
SCAP/OVAL instead of C-80703r1_chk
Result  notchecked
```

This error happens for all the checks. I haven't found anything here or on Google about this: it looks like the OSCAP input file is correct, but the checks are all failing because the system isn't registered with Canonical. This is true, but I have no way to remediate that, so I'm hoping there's a way to fix this.

The command I'm using is:

```
oscap xccdf eval --profile MAC-1_Public \
--results $(hostname -f).openscap-xccdf-results.xml \
--report $(hostname -f).openscap-xccdf-report.html \
U_Canonical_Ubuntu_16-04_LTS_STIG_V1R2_Manual-xccdf.xml
```

I tried the --skip-valid option, but that didn't fix anything.

I'm new to running these scans, so apologies if I've made a rookie error.